# julia @parallel for loop does not update array

Tags: for-loop, multidimensional-array, parallel-processing, julia

I am new to julia and to get started I wanted to port some numpy code to julia and hoped to get some nice performance increase. So far not to my satisfaction.

This is the function I want to compute

```
function s(x_list, r_list)
    result_list = zeros(size(x_list,1))
    for i = 1:size(x_list,1)
        dotprods = r_list * x_list[i,:]'
        expcall  = exp(im * dotprods)
        sumprod  = sum(expcall) * sum(conj(expcall))
        result_list[i] = sumprod
    end
    return result_list
end
```

with data input that looks like

```
v = rand(3)
r = rand(6000,3)
x = linspace(1.0, 2.0, 300) * (v./sqrt(sumabs2(v)))'
```

for this function and the given input, `@time s(x,r)` gives me

```
0.110619 seconds (3.60 k allocations: 96.256 MB, 8.47% gc time)
```

For this case, numpy does the same job in ~70ms, so I'm not very happy! Now if I do a `@parallel for` loop with `julia -p 2`:

```
function s(x_list, r_list)
    result_list = SharedArray(Float64, size(x_list,1))
    @parallel for i = 1:size(x_list,1)
        dotprods = r_list * x_list[i,:]'
        expcall  = exp(im * dotprods)
        sumprod  = sum(expcall) * sum(conj(expcall))
        result_list[i] = sumprod
    end
    return result_list
end
```

the problem is that

```
result_list[i] = sumprod
```

doesn't get updated and I get the list of zeros returned from the array initialization. What am I doing wrong here? 
Further attempts to increase speed also did not show any benefit, e.g.

```
@vectorize_2arg Array{Float64,2} s
```

and declaring types

```
function s{T<:Float64}(x_list::Array{T,2}, r_list::Array{T,2})
```

But now, starting the same `@parallel for` loop in a session with just one thread (no `-p2`, just `julia`) the array does get updated and `@time s(x,r)` tells me

```
0.000040 seconds (36 allocations: 4.047 KB)
```

which is actually impossible for the function and input given! Is this a bug?

Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that you're not waiting for the `@parallel` call to complete. From [the docs](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/parallel-computing/#parallel-map-and-loops):

> ...the reduction operator can be omitted if it is not needed. In that case, the loop executes asynchronously, i.e. it spawns independent tasks on all available workers and returns an array of Future immediately without waiting for completion. The caller can wait for the Future completions at a later point by calling `fetch()` on them, or wait for completion at the end of the loop by prefixing it with `@sync`, like `@sync @parallel for`.

Try prefixing for loop with `@sync`

Comment: thanks, that @sync actually did it! As for the other part, are there other things one can do to speed up julia to achieve sort of similar or better performance then python/numpy in single process mode?

Answer (score 3):

Julia's `@parallel` macro does a distributed for loop: it copies all the data to other *processes* and does computations on each of them, reducing over the results and returning that result. The processes do not share memory – and may even be on other machines altogether. Your original data is never touched because each worker is modifying its own copy of that data. You may be thinking of threads, which is a currently-experimental feature that Julia will be adding in the future.

Comment: Oh sorry forgot to mention that I also used a SharedArray for the @parallel for loop. This should actually take care of the copying. Will modify my question to make this obvious!